# full bandwidth utilization or bad connection?

Tags: connection, isp, utilization

We have a certain size dedicated pipe from our ISP.  Lately, our connection has been slow and intermittent.

How can I tell if its because we are fully / over utilizing the pipe?  Or if its a problem at our ISPs end?

Our connection is overall slow.  Additionally, sites fail to load from time to time.  Connections to FTP servers are dropped. among other issues.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I use Cacti (http://www.cacti.net/) to monitor our network traffic (among other things) and determine how much bandwidth we're using during peak times.

Answer (score 2):

I would first contact that ISP and have them check the line and see if they can give you your own usage statistics.

To gather your own, you can likely monitor either your switch or router and get usage statistics with something like SNMP.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, remove your network. Directly connect a single computer and run some bandwidth tests. Ping your DNS and watch for changes in response time. Most likely at this point you will find that some computer on your network has been owned and is using up bandwidth.
The best ways to find rogue bandwidth users can vary. If you have a routed connection, check your router logs. SNMP is also useful. Also look to applications like [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for monitoring.

Comment: Good suggestion, chances are he simply has a few botnet infected desktops :-)